# Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I'm using MVCContrib and its [EmailTemplateService](http://codevanced.net/post/Sending-HTML-emails-with-ASPNET-MVC2-and-MVCContrib.asp) to send html email. 
Send email works fine but it doesn't seem to dispose email view properly. When I try to redirect to a new Action it gives the following error:

"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent"

Does anyone know how to fix this problem. Many thanks

Sandra

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    //do the redirect
```